# How to make solver to move one cell to the right after ready calculations?

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I have set up solver to... solve but I need him to move one cell to the right and do the same calculations. I have 50 cells to calculate and doing it manually is not the thing I want.

I include an image of what I need:

[image: https://ibb.co/9GD0C7v]

```
Sub Macro2()

'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    SolverOk SetCell:="$G$28", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$G$27", Engine _
        :=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"

    SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$28", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="$G$26"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$G$28", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$G$27", Engine _

        :=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:="$G$28", MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$G$27", Engine _

        :=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve

End Sub
```

My solver should do the following:

Find a number in cell A3 which will meet following rules:

1. A4 (result of A3 * 6000) must be higher than A2 but as low as possible (that's why I used MIN for excel). For this example I know that number is 16.8.
2. Place the number in A3 and move to B3.
3. Repeat point 1 but for numbers in column B.

Comment: How does the code you've posted relate to your picture?

Comment: It appears you have simply recorded an instance of Solver and posted its code here. I have not spent much time trying to understand your specific needs, but I believe you need to use a for loop to iterate over the cells you want to apply your Solver on. Simply put everything inside a for loop and change the target cell, and if necessary the restrictions. If you don't know how a for loop works, here is a tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JyWrLH7monI